# ClassNotFoundException while running web service with tomcat 7?

Tags: java, web-services, oim

I am developing a webservice and got following error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey RESTful App] in context with path [/RestWebService] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/CreateException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.CreateException
```

As i am dealing with **oim** api so i have also added the **wlfullclient.jar** in class path. `/WEB-INF/lib folder`.

After addling that jar also the exception is still there.

Comment: restart your application server after redeploy the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the JAR file from here [j2ee-1.4.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadj2ee14jar.htm)

Put it on your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Add `CLASSPATH`. Then restart server.

Answer (score 0):

The class is located in `j2ee-1.4.jar`. please download and add it to your classpath.